# How to extract the templated type from a perfect-forwarding function with homogeneous templated-type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, stdvector, perfect-forwarding

I wish to write a variadic factory function to forward a variable number of parameters (of the same type) to construct and populate a `std::vector`. However I'm not sure how to extract the elements' type from the "perfect forward" mechanism, thus have this type deduced automatically by the compiler, and use it to set the vector's type.

In essence:

```
    template <typename T>
    struct Object { T x {}; };

    Object<int> x1 {1};
    Object<int> x2 {2};

    auto collection = make_objects(x1, x2, Object<int>(3));

    // 'collection' is a std::vector<Object<int>> with elements that are copies of x1, x2, and the third rvalue parameter. 

    // note that `make_objects` deduced all types it needed.
```

I'm using C++20 - full code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TGWqcMd9j).

---

Let's start with a basic concrete struct:

```
struct Object {
    int x {};
};
```

I wish to create a collection of an arbitrary number of these, using `std::vector` as the container. I have a "factory" function called `make_objects` that takes a variable number of Object instances, by lvalue and/or rvalue, and perfect-forwards them to the vector's `emplace_back()` member function:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto make_objects(Args&&... args) {
    std::vector<Object> vec;
    vec.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
    (vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    return vec;
}
```

The means the client code is mostly unaware of the collection type (or at least can rely on `auto`), and can do the following:

```
int main() {

    Object x1 {1};
    Object x2 {2};

    auto objects = make_objects(x1, x2, Object(3));

    for (auto o: objects) {
        std::cout << o << '\n';
    }
}
```

So far so good.

Now I want to make my `Object` more generic by converting it to a template, so I change it to this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Object {
    T x {};
};
```

At this point I'm stumped on how to write the `make_objects` factory function. My first attempt is:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_objects(Args&&... args) {
    std::vector<T> vec;  // how to specify this type?
    vec.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
    (vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    return vec;
}
```

This doesn't compile unless it is called with an explicit `T`, i.e.  `make_objects<Object<int>>`. Otherwise the type T is not deducible.

Is there a way to do this kind of perfect forwarding such that the homogeneous type being forwarded can be extracted and used in the forwarding function?

Note that I wish to avoid the following kinds of syntax:

`make_objects<int>(x, ...)` - I want the type of Object to be deduced from the parameters, but they are all the same type at least (maybe `std::same_as` or `std::convertible_to` can be used here to enforce that?).

`make_objects({x, ...})` - I don't want to use an initializer list in this situation because ultimately I need the parameters to be non-const as there are intended side-effects I've left out for clarity.

I have been studying [Homogeneous function parameter packs](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/param-pack.html#homogeneous-intro) but this seems to suffer from the same problem, in that everything works if `Obj` is a concrete class, but gives no clues (that I've picked up on) as to how to handle a templated `Obj<T>`.

Comment: Is your question simply: "my variadic function's parameters are all type `T`, so I'd like to declare a vector of T"? If so, whether `T` is itself a non-template type, or a template type, is completely irrelevant. You might be happy to learn that all you need to do is to forward the values as an initializer-list to `std::vector`, and it'll deduce what it is, by itself. You don't need to do it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, I think so, although the problem is the function that does this _thing_ (`make_objects`) needs to have a signature that uses a _variadic_ template parameter because there may be an arbitrary number of parameters, and I chose perfect-forwarding as some might be rvalues and I thought it good to avoid unnecessary copies. Perhaps your suggestion makes more sense. Would you mind writing an answer to describe what you mean, please? There's definitely a possibility that I'm going about this the wrong/difficult way.

Comment: @JaMiT yeah, sorry, an inadvertent carry-over from when I had a type alias for the `std::vector`, which I removed to help with clarity. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

`make_objects` could simply be:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
auto make_objects(Args&&... args) {
    // use the std::vector deduction guide:
    return std::vector{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

Then, this will will work:

```cpp
int main() {
    Object x1 {1};
    Object x2 {2};

    auto objects1 = make_objects(x1, x2);

    //auto objects2 = make_objects(x1, x2, Object{3});   // C++17
    auto objects2 = make_objects(x1, x2, Object(3));
    
    for (auto o: objects2) {
        std::cout << o << '\n';
    }
}
```

If you want `Object{3}` to work work in C++17, add a deduction guide:

```cpp
template<class T> Object(T) -> Object<T>;
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it's a lot simpler than I was expecting. In fact my code didn't even need the deduction guide - your `make_objects` function "just works" in my case. Are there any negative implications to leaving out the deduction guide?

Comment: @davidA _"negative implications"_ - not really if you are only targeting C++20 and above. For C++17, the guide is needed. I edited the answer to make that clear.

Comment: @davidA One possible drawback with leaving the deduction guide out is that clang doesn't seem to deduce `T` without it. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/WjWzPPGbW). That surprised me ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to explicitly name the deduced type, you can do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
auto make_objects(Head&& head, Tail&&... tail) {
    using T = std::remove_cvref_t<Head>;
    static_assert(std::conjunction_v<
        std::is_same<T, std::remove_cvref_t<Tail>>...>);
    // Do something with T
}
```

Comment: This looks useful - thank you. It looks like it also ensures that the variadic types are all the same, is that right? Would `std::convertible_to` be a good substitute for `std::is_same` if I need it to handle const and non-const together, or will `std::is_same` handle that OK?

Comment: Yes, the `static_assert` is used to ensure all types are the same. `std::conjunction` is logical AND in meta programming. `std::remove_cvref_t` handles const and non-constness. You could also use `std::convertible_to` or `std::is_convertible` if you want to allow callers to pass arguments convertible to `T`. Then however you can't really deduce `T` from the first argument without assigning it a special role as authority for deduction of T. To work around that you could use `std::common_type` to deduce T, but asserting the parameters are all the same is probably the saner approach.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that - I did wonder how to work around the first parameter being "special" and you've shown me how to do it.